# CodingBat split53; Confused about the right way to use returns

Tags: java, recursion, function-call

I am a bit confused as to why my solution below, is not giving the proper answer. I did some digging and I'm guessing it has to do with the way the calls work? I thought that both ways were the same but that is not the case, but I do not completely understand what mine is returning incorrectly. This is the research I did before hand: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/333247/why-does-recursion-return-the-first-call-in-the-stack-and-not-the-last

Problem:

Given an array of ints, is it possible to divide the ints into two groups, so that the sum of the two groups is the same, with these constraints: all the values that are multiple of 5 must be in one group, and all the values that are a multiple of 3 (and not a multiple of 5) must be in the other. (No loops needed.)

Example:

split53([1, 1]) → true

split53([1, 1, 1]) → false

split53([2, 4, 2]) → true

My Answer:

```
public boolean split53Helper(int start, int [] nums, int group3, int group5){
  if(start >= nums.length){
    return group3 == group5;
  }

  if(nums[start] % 3 == 0 ){
    if (split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5)){
      return true;
    }
  }

  if(nums[start] % 5 == 0){
    if (split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start])){
      return true;
    }
  }

  if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5))
      return true;

  if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start]))
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

Correct Solution:

```
public boolean split53(int[] nums) {
    return split53Helper(0, nums, 0, 0);
}

public boolean split53Helper(int start, int[] nums, int mult5, int mult3) {
    if(start >= nums.length)
        return mult5 == mult3;

    if(nums[start] % 5 == 0)
        return split53Helper(start+1, nums, mult5 + nums[start], mult3);

    if(nums[start] % 3 == 0)
        return split53Helper(start+1, nums, mult5, mult3 + nums[start]);

    if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, mult5 + nums[start], mult3))
        return true;

    if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, mult5, mult3 + nums[start]))
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Is my code not returning the last call? 
If so, when would I use one method of returning over the other? If there is already a thorough explanation just let me know. I thought I understood how the stacks and function calls worked but now I'm worried I'm moving in the wrong direction.

Comment: What problem is `split53` trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, I added the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the correct solution, rewritten to look more similar to your answer:

```
public boolean split53Helper(int start, int [] nums, int group3, int group5){
  if(start >= nums.length){
    return group3 == group5;
  }

  if(nums[start] % 3 == 0 ){
    if (split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5)){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false; // <-------
    }
  }

  if(nums[start] % 5 == 0){
    if (split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start])){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false; // <-------
    }
  }

  if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5))
      return true;

  if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start]))
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

Now you should see how your answer is different from the correct solution. If the first recursive call returns false, your answer would continue on to call the third and fourth recursive call, whereas the correct solution will not.

When a recursive method deals with arrays, it almost always follows this "do something to one element, and then (recursively) do it to the rest of the elements" pattern. The recursive calls are asking "can the rest of the array be divided into 2 groups that sums to the same number...?".

When an element is divisible by 3, you put it in the 3's group and ask that same question, hence calling:

```
split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5)
```

If the answer to this question is "no", you shouldn't then ask "well what if I put it in the 5's group?" (I'm referring to the 4th recursive call in your answer)

```
split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start])
```

You can't put it in the 5's group because the element is known to be divisible by 3.

This is why you should return immediately when you know it's divisible by 3, and the rest *can't* be divided into groups.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below explanation of correct solution.
I think, The solution is scanning numbers stored in nums and checking if its divisible by 3 or 5 or none of them.

In case its divisible by 3, You add it to group3 and move on to next number.
In case its divisible by 5, you add it to group5 and move on to next number.
In case its not divisible by none, you try adding to both and move on to next number
Once you scanned all the numbers, You check if group3 equals to group5

```
public boolean split53Helper(int start, int [] nums, int group3, int group5){
      if(start >= nums.length){
        return group3 == group5;
      }

      if(nums[start] % 3 == 0 ){
         /**
          * In this case you dont have any choice as the number is divisble by 3.
          * You should add the number to group3 and move on with next number.
          * Dont put the below statement in if condition
          */
        return split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5);
      }

      if(nums[start] % 5 == 0){
        /**
          * In this case you dont have any choice as the number is divisble by 5.
          * You should add the number to group5 and move on with next number.
          * Dont put the below statement in if condition
          */
        return split53Helper(start + 1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start]);
      }

      // Here you have choice, you can either put the number in group3 or group5

      if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3 + nums[start], group5))
          return true;

      if(split53Helper(start+1, nums, group3, group5 + nums[start]))
          return true;

      return false;
    }
```